# Bold type and commas

Tags: commas, writing-style, typography

**This is a bold statement,** but this is normal.

The first clause is written in bold. Should the comma be bold or not?

Comment: As with many questions, it is impossible to put the genie back in the bottle, so maybe we should just try to help anyway?

Comment: Perhaps use the same rule for punctuation inside or outside quotation marks.

Answer (score 7):

This is strictly a matter of style—and one on which (as is so often the case) preferences vary.

*The Chicago Manual of Style*, fifteenth edition (2003) lays out consistent approaches to both a "primary system" for handling punctuation and font issues, and a "more traditional system":

> **6.3** *Punctuation and font: primary system.* All punctuation marks should appear in the same font—roman or italic—as the main or surrounding text, except for punctuation that belongs to a title or an exclamation in a different font. ...
>
> ...
>
> **6.5** *Punctuation and font: alternative system.* According to a more traditional system, periods, commas, colons, and semicolons should appear in the same font as the word, letter, character, or symbol immediately preceding them if different from that of the main or surrounding text. ...

So that covers just about all of the possibilities, doesn't it? Incidentally, the specific issue of boldface type is covered in guideline 6.4, between the two quoted above:

> **6.4** *Boldface.* Punctuation marks following boldface should be dealt with case by case, depending on how the boldface word is used. [Examples omitted.]

Most of the house style guides I've dealt with at various book publishers specify regular roman punctuation after a boldface term that appears (usually as a highlighted key term) in running text. But again, it's ultimately a style issue, not a rule of language and usage.

Answer (score -2):

I regard the comma as merely defining the structure within which the thoughts are placed, so would not embolden it. Consider this example in which I use a (rather unnecessary) comma:

*Italics are for emphasis*, **and bold is for effect**. How could one sensibly decide if the comma were to be bold or italic? One cannot, so it must remain plain.

Comment: What is the difference between emphasis and effect? Bold is mostly used in bad typesetting. You don’t see it in literature. That’s what italic is for.

Comment: Actually, you can. The comma is attached to a word, and takes that word's style (italics, in this case).